# Can a shader sample a block/region of pixels in a texture?

Tags: 3d, glsl, hlsl, shader, cg

Are there ways a shader can query the sum/average of a block of pixels in a texture read, rather than looking up a single value? I'm working in Cg but any examples and search terms are welcome.

I specifically mean built-in ways, NOT looping manually in my shader.

Comment: Can you build a mipmap and sample the texture at a certain level? Trilinear sampling for square blocks is a must, but I don't know how to sample non-square blocks even with anisotropic filtering.

Comment: MipMaps could be a good call. I do literally want to sample the texture at lower resolution  - the only caveat is it's a render-texture, I am applying post=process effects by rendering as normal, then using the output into a full-screen quad with a post-process shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

The best you can do is the [ARB_texture_gather extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_gather.txt) (core in GL 4.0+)/[D3D10.1's gather function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb944003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This allows you to fetch from a 2x2 block of texels, but you only get *one* component of that texture at a time. Further, the pure extension/D3D10.1 version can *only* fetch the Red component of the texture. The GL 4.0/D3D11.0 version can fetch any of the four components, but each call will *only* fetch one.

Of course, you have to do the averaging of the 2x2 block yourself.

The only really viable alternative is to do what Lyth said: generate mipmaps for your texture and sample from them. The texture accessing functions can fetch from a specific mipmap, which represents an average of a particular range of pixels. And of course, those are limited as well.

Comment: I'm sampling a render-texture; do you any idea how performant it is to create mip-maps in this case? I _presume_ it's done on the GPU?

Comment: @John: It depends on exactly what you want to do. Mipmap generation can be done however the hardware wants; if you have specific needs, then you'll have to do it manually. Mipmap generation also generates all mipmaps between the base layer and the max layer; it could be more efficient to manually generate just the average you want directly. The best way to find out is to try it and see if it's fast enough. If it is, then use it until it stops being fast enough. If not, then write your own.